# AWS-Quicksight - how to count log entries, so that unique values with same OR different status flags are aggregated?

Tags: business-intelligence, amazon-quicksight

Hard to find a title for that question:

We have a database that is structured like this:

Timestamp - ProductID - Status Flag (a, b)- .... (other fields)

We have AWS Quicksight, but the question is generic enough I think ...

We would now like to get information on (per given timeframe; e.g. weekly)
* How many (unique/distinct) product IDs are there in the DB?
*  How many (unique) productIDs with Status Flag "a"?
* How many (distinct) productIDs with Status Flag "b"?
* Now the challenge: How many productIDs with BOTH a and b?

Theoretically, the answer to the last question would be:
No. of ProductIDs with Status Flag a + No. of ProductIDs with Status Flag b - No. of ProductIDs.

But is this really the best way? Or is there something better that wouldn't break if there comes a flag "c" ?

You may think of Status Flags as "is in Warehouse A"; "is in Warehouse B". 
We want to see items that went through both warehouses, as well as those that only went to "A" or "B".